# Laravel selecting all rows just once if same some_id

Tags: sql, laravel

Suppose I have a product table in which there are those columns: id, user_id
How can I retrieve all the rows of this table just once if two rows have the same user_id in Laravel?

Comment: When there are multiple rows per `user_id`, which one do you want to get?

Comment: can I use where other_id = ?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: id: 1,2,3,4,5 - user_id: 1,1,2,3,4 I want something like this: SELECT * FROM product JUST ONCE if the following user_id are the same, so in this example it will retrieve only the rows with id 1,3,4,5

Comment: What did you mean by your first comment? Do you want to get the product with the lowest/highest `order_id` (if a `user_id` has multiple products)?

Comment: let it be, I think it will be easier if I create another table indexing it from the previous one, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return all columns in the product model without any duplicates of user_id. So, it will return, just one row per user_id.

```
$productModel->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```